# How to enable finish button in JWizard plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwizard

I'm showing forms dynamically and some forms comes with only 1 step.

How can I enable finish button when I have only one step in JWizard plugin?

Comment: Could you include some sample code of what you have so far?

Comment: $(".jWizard").on(
                       "stephide", function(){
                            if(!$("form").validationEngine('validate')){
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                ).jWizard({
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: false,
                        finish:{
                            "class": "finished",
                            type:"button"
                        }
                    }
                });